# Extjs grid property change listeners not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have one property grid...

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
        id          : "PROPERTIES",
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 300,
        viewConfig : {
            forceFit: true,
            scrollOffset: 2 // the grid will never have scrollbars
        },
        listeners   :{
            propertychange:function(source,recordId,value,oldValue){
                alert(Ext.encode(source));
                alert(recordId);
                alert("new Value="+value);
            }
        },
        source  : {
            "title"         : "My Object",
            "color"         : Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
            "Available"     : false,
            "Version"       : 0.01,
            "Description"   : "A test object"
        }
    });
```

**My Query**

When any values in the "source" changed, I need one listener to catch the changes.
Suppose if user try to change the "title" from "My Object" to "Title1". How can I catch the new "title".

Note: In this grid I given one listeners "propertychange". But no effect!

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ext JS are you using? With Ext JS 4.2.1 your code works as you want, `propertychange` event is fired when you change any property: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ct

Comment: `Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
            handler:function(){
                Ext.getCmp("PROPERTIES").setSource({
                    "title": "Tikgh"
                });
            },
            text:"Change Source",
            renderTo:Ext.getBody()
        });`    Please check this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setSource`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-setSource) method sets whole source data object containing the property data.

If you want to change only some property value you should use [`setProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-setProperty) method which sets the value of a property and fire `propertychange` event:

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    handler: function() {
        Ext.getCmp("PROPERTIES").setProperty("title", "Tikgh");
    },
    text: "Change Source",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Fiddle with live example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ct**

Comment: Perfect!! This is what I want.. Thanks a lot.. Akatum